# Heroku console throws dependency error on 'railties'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.0.beta1 with Ruby 1.9.3 on Cedar and I cannot access my production Rails console.  All the solutions to this error on Stack Overflow are solutions to a local development environment, not Heroku.

```
heroku run console --app myapp
```

When using Ruby 1.9.3, errors are:

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.2461
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [activerecord-deprecated_finders-0.0.3, annotate-2.5.0, arel-4.0.0, atomic-1.1.9, aws-sdk-1.11.1, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bigdecimal-1.1.0, builder-3.1.4, bundler-1.3.2, coffee-rails-4.0.0, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.6.2, curb-0.8.4, dotenv-0.8.0, eco-1.0.0, eco-source-1.1.0.rc.1, ejs-1.0.0, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.4.0, foreman-0.63.0, hike-1.2.3, i18n-0.6.4, io-console-0.3, jquery-rails-3.0.1, json-1.8.0, json-1.5.5, kgio-2.8.0, mail-2.5.4, messengerjs-rails-1.3.3, mime-types-1.23, mini_portile-0.5.0, minitest-4.7.4, minitest-2.5.1, multi_json-1.7.7, nokogiri-1.6.0, orm_adapter-0.4.0, pg-0.15.1, polyglot-0.3.3, protected_attributes-1.0.1, rack-1.5.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-backbone-0.7.2, rails_12factor-0.0.2, rails_on_heroku-0.0.2, rails_serve_static_assets-0.0.1, rails_stdout_logging-0.0.1, raindrops-0.11.0, rake-10.1.0, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.12.2, rdoc-3.9.5, sass-3.2.9, sass-rails-4.0.0.rc2, sprockets-2.10.0, sprockets-rails-2.0.0, thor-0.18.1, thread_safe-0.1.0, tilt-1.4.1, treetop-1.4.14, tzinfo-0.3.37, uglifier-2.1.1, unicorn-4.6.3, uuidtools-2.1.4, valid_email-0.0.4, warden-1.2.1] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

When using Ruby 2.0.0, errors are:

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.1088
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 67 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

When I drop into a Heroku bash shell and issue `gem list`, railties is not found.

I've tried to manually install it with `gem install railties` in bash on Heroku which installs it but does not fix the issue.

I've added railties in my Gemfile (although it should be automatically depended on) which didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running `bundle install --binstubs` locally, adding the files to my git repository, and re-pushing to Heroku.